# What does C$ mean when entered in Windows/Run while accessing remote drive?

Tags: windows, network-shares

If I enter in the Windows Run "\_some_ip\c$" I go the remote C: drive. What does the C$ stand for and why isn't it C: ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shares with a $ are hidden shares (also called "Administrative shares" as mentioned by [Diskilla](https://superuser.com/users/33300/diskilla)) and thus not visible when requesting the share list of a device.

There are several default hidden shares active by default on your system:

- One for every drive available:

  - (A$)
  - C$
  - (D$)
  - etc.
- To C:\WINDOWS: ADMIN$
- Printer sharing: print$
- [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (Inter-process communication) interface: IPC$

For more information about (creating and removing) hidden shares, check out the [Microsoft Knowledge base on this topic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984).

If you right click "(My) Computer" -> "Manage" -> Select "Shared Folders" on the left -> Go to "Shares", you'll see something like this (but in your language of course). This one is in Dutch:

[image: Shared Folders]

Comment: also known as administrative shares.

Comment: @Diskilla indeed...